# how to save a zoomed-in copy of a swf file

Tags: flash

I have a swf page that I would like to convert to a png file. 
Before I convert the file, I would like to zoom in to the swf file so that I have a larger image. 
I try swftools to convert, but the png image quality is not good enough: Zoomed-in png image looks too blurry.

What do you suggest I should do to capture/use a zoomed-in version of a swf file. 
A linux compatible command line tool would be great as I am thinking of converting hundreds of images.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

It's not a linux way, but I can't imagine nothing else.

My solution is to write AIR application, which loads swf file, adds it to its screen, makes a "prinscreen" and saves the printscreen to the png.

1) every display object can be drawn on `BitmapData` with additional transforming control (you need scaling), e.g.:

```
var btn:Button = new Button;
var bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height);
var m:Matrix = new Matrix;
m.scale(2, 2);
bitmap.draw(btn, m);
```

More on this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29

2) `BitmapData` can be converted to png and saved. To convert you can use built-in `PNGEncoder`. The output `BiteArray` can be saved to specified file:

```
var bitmap:BitmapData = makeScreenShot();
var encoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
var bytes:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bitmap);
var imgStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
var img:File = new File(path);
imgStream.open(img, FileMode.WRITE);
imgStream.writeBytes(bytes);
imgStream.close();
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html

Additionaly, as PNGEncoder is slow, you can write your own using [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy), since pnglib is ported (it is in sdk examples).

3) You can pass pathes to swfs to AIR app in command line arguments:

```
<mx:WindowedApplication
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    invoke="onInvoke(event)">
    ...

private function onInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void
{
    for each (str:String in event.arguments)
        //do something
}
```

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_do_I_use_command_line_arguments_with_my_AIR_ap-8003.html

Comment: it seems that I won't be able to convert files in bulk then? Is that correct? Do you think it it is worth trying (installing, learning the syntax etc..)?

Comment: You will be able to convert files in bulk. As I mentioned, AIR apps support arguments, so you can pass a list of swfs to it and convert consecutevly. As for me, it is worth trying, but I don't need learning ^^. Another reason - it seems, that it's the simlest solution (if not the only).